# Script to add MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION to MSI

Tags: windows-installer

Anyone have a script (JScript, VBScript or similar) in the spirit of [this handy script](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2007/05/28/2958062.aspx) but adding the [MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa816403(VS.85).aspx) property

I know I could use Orca manually or with its transform feature, but would rather not go there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some refs

- [Windows Installer SDK - Execute SQL Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368568(VS.85).aspx)
- [wirunsql.vbs](http://www.koders.com/noncode/fid9C9C2D7366257C7CD2F39E21D97397EB035201BE.aspx)

Modifying the CustomAction_NoImpersonate.js referenced in the question gives this script which can add/set any value in the Properties table.

Call with "cscript.exe MSI_SetProperty.js your.msi property value"

```
// MSI_SetProperty.js <msi-file> <property> <value>
// Performs a post-build fixup of an msi to set the specified property (and add it if it doesn't already exist)

// Constant values from Windows Installer SDK
var msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact = 1;
var msiViewModifyInsert         = 1;
var msiViewModifyUpdate         = 2;  

if (WScript.Arguments.Length != 3)
{
    WScript.StdErr.WriteLine("Usage: " + WScript.ScriptName + "file property value");
    WScript.Quit(1);
}

var filespec = WScript.Arguments(0);
var property = WScript.Arguments(1);
var value = parseInt(WScript.Arguments(2));
var installer = WScript.CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
var database = installer.OpenDatabase(filespec, msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact);

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Looking for property:" + property);

try
{   
    var sql = "SELECT Property, Value FROM Property WHERE Property = '" + property + "'";   
    var view = database.OpenView(sql);  
    view.Execute();     
    var record = view.Fetch();  

    if (record)
    {       
        while (record)
        {
            WScript.StdOut.Write("Found: " + record.StringData(0) + ", " + record.StringData(1) + ", " + record.StringData(2));
            if (record.IntegerData(2) != value)
            {
                WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(" - changing to " + value);
                record.IntegerData(2) = value;
                view.Modify(msiViewModifyUpdate,record);
            }
            else
                WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(" - OK");

            record = view.Fetch();
        }
    }
    else
    {           
        WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Not found, so adding");
        // There may be a better way to do this?
        sql = "INSERT INTO Property (Property,Value) VALUES ('" + property + "','" + value + "')";
        view = database.OpenView(sql);
        view.Execute();     
    }
    view.Close();
    database.Commit();
}
catch(e)
{
    WScript.StdErr.WriteLine(e);
    WScript.Quit(1);
}
```

Comment: What is the hex value of MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION. or do you simply set MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION?The reason, I ask this when i run the script, it always goes in the else block and a new property gets added. also, my installer still seems to be running under system account and not the user account