# Starting services in installer gives not sufficient priviliges

Tags: c#, windows-services, uac

I have an installer which installs services and then starts them.

On some machines with UAC on, when the service is about the start the installer fails with "insufficient priviliges".

Should I raise the priviliges of the installer (if at all possible)? or is there another means of getting the service to start?

JD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think installing a service itself will require admin privileges.

Since you know that the service cannot start since the installer does not have sufficient privilege, [embed a manifest](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/28/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Demand-UAC-elevation-for-an-application-by-adding-a-manifest-using-mt.exe.aspx) asking for admin rights (asAdministrator). If you are using Installshield 12 or above, it will automatically embed a manifest for you.

Comment: @Ganesh R: I am using Wix 3 and on a vista machine on occasions we have had to "run as administrator" to get the install working (i.e. service does not start otherwise) but on a Windows 2008 server machine, there was no option to "run as administrator".

Comment: JD Windows Server 2008 is based on source code of Windows Vista SP1. In all OSes after Vista, you will find the "Run As Administrator" option. (need to do that while launching the installer)

Comment: Since Wix 3 creates MSI packages, you may find this post useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304353/mark-msi-so-it-has-to-be-run-as-elevated-administrator-account