# Force msi to just run as administrator

Tags: windows-installer, setup-project

I have a `.MSI` file that is generated with VS2017 setup project. How can i force the `MSI` installer to just run as administrator? I've read about `Launch Condition`, but i'm not sure if it is the solution or not and also i don't know the syntax of `Condition`.

Comment: Do you want to prevent per-user installation? (installation only accessible for one user with files installed to the user profile). The Windows UAC will prompt for elevation when faced with an MSI that must be installed per-machine ([ALLUSERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/allusers)=1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mark MSI so it has to be run as elevated Administrator account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304353/mark-msi-so-it-has-to-be-run-as-elevated-administrator-account)